# How to remove the unwanted characters from the string using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to remove the some character from given string.

```
$mystring = 'test1 ( 07/07/2016) x 1 - 300.00 test2 test 2 (12/7/2016) x 1 - 82.00';
```

Here, I need get only test1 and test2 test2  How can I achieve this?

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? (You should update your question with your current attempt(s).)

Comment: So you only need to remove this ( 07/07/2016) x 1 - 300.00 from the string? Or something else too?

Comment: You can use `str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)`

Comment: `How can I achieve this ?` Do some code and read PHP Docs on string replace. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to fetch any date and then your string

```
$mystring = 'test1 ( 07/07/2016) x 1 - 300.00 test2 test 2 (12/7/2016) x 1 - 82.00';

$mystring = preg_replace('#\( ?\d\d/\d?\d/\d\d\d\d\) ?x ?1 ?- ?[\d\.]+#', '', $mystring);
echo $mystring;
```

Comment: You should *explain* your answer.

Comment: I need to get test1 ,test2 test2

Comment: @soniya at the begining you've said sth deifferent... Ok, I updated my answer again

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Try this:

```
$mystring = 'test1 ( 07/07/2016) x 1 - 300.00 test2 test 2 (12/7/2016) x 1 - 82.00';
$removable_string = "( 07/07/2016) x 1 - 300.00";
echo str_replace($removable_string, '', $mystring); // test1 test2 test 2 (12/7/2016) x 1 - 82.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_replace()` with the first argument as an array of Regular Expressions, you could filter out unwanted Texts, leaving only the relevant ones like so:

```
   <?php

        $myString       = 'test1 ( 07/07/2016) x 1 - 300.00 test2 test 2 (12/7/2016) x 1 - 82.00';

        // REMOVE ALL DATES WITHIN PARENTHESIS AS WELL AS ALL STRINGS NOT
        // RELATED TO THE STRING test FROM THE STRING $myString USING
        // preg_replace WITH AN ARRAY OF REGEX AS 1ST PARAMETER:
        $rxDates        = array(
            "#(\(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\))#si",
            "#(\(\s*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\))#si",
            "#(x\s*\d{1}\s*\-\s*\d{1,7}\.\d{2})#si",
        );
        $cleanString    = trim(preg_replace($rxDates, "", $myString));

        var_dump($cleanString);
        // DUMPS:==> 'test1   test2 test 2'

        // YOU CAN GO A STEP FURTHER REMOVING SPACES AS IN 'test 2'
        $cleanString    = preg_replace("#(test)(\s*)(\d*)#", "$1$3", $cleanString);

        var_dump($cleanString);
        // DUMPS:==> 'test1   test2 test2'

        // YOU MAY WANT TO PUT THEM IN AN ARRAY IN WHICH CASE 
        // YOU MAY DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS:
        $arrCleanString = preg_split("#\s{1,10}#", $cleanString);

        var_dump($arrCleanString);
        // DUMPS:               
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'test1' (length=5)
          1 => string 'test2' (length=5)
          2 => string 'test2' (length=5)
```